# SonarQube Build Breaker Plugin Hangs Up

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

One of our Jenkins jobs is hanging up when it reaches the Build Breaker execution:-

Problem Details:-
https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker/issues/26

There are other jobs with the same configuration and similar features but they go through while this one hangs up for 2 hours approximately.

Can someone tell us how to fix this please? We feel that it could possibly be because of the Thread.sleep statement on the QualityGateBreaker.java file ( see the above link for the source code)? However, we are not sure if this is true.

Appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Build Breaker isn't recommended](https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/) Instead, [look at webhooks](https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/)

Comment: Thanks Ann for the quick response. We still need the above issue resolved for the short term since we are on 5.6.5 for now. However, we are going to use this feature as soon as we upgrade to 6.7 LTS ( when it comes out). Appreciate it!